# seeking UV Stretch colour related information

Tags: uv, workflow, uv-image-editor

i have unwrapped a object in blender and when i turn on the display stetch,it shows the blue and light blue clour.I know blue means no stetching and red means high stetching. The question is what other colurs reflect inforamtion regarding stretching. Do we always have a blue colur on our uv or light blue or even green is acceptable.What would be the best colur to have in your uv for good uvs thnx[image]

Comment: as you say, blue is the best, red is the worst, it goes from blue to red, going through green, yellow, orange, so it looks like you don't have too much stretching here

Comment: thnx for help, should i always go for the dark blue or some kind of this light blue is applicable for good uvs?

Comment: dark blue is the best, but you can't always have dark blue with some objects, there must be some ways to optimize the stretching though (some functions in the UV Editor or some addons)

Comment: For example in the UV Editor > header menu > UV > Minimize Stretch